# How can I install the qt-mt (Qt multithreaded) library on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: software-installation, application-development, qt

I'm trying to install some software for a Mightex camera and the first step is to run a `./configure` file, after getting a lot of messages where it checks for libraries it fails with the following:

```
checking if Qt is multi-threaded... no
Qt is not multithreaded (or its name is wrong). You MUST have a multithreaded
version of the Qt library installed or CamStream will simply not compile.
```

I think this is the relevant part of the `configure` file with regards to this message.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/9620162/

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.

This link seems to indicate I need to install `libqt-mt` but I can't find that, or any other qt related library that is multithreaded.

**UPDATE**

After a bit more searching I found the package here:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/libqt3-mt

But it seems that qt3 is very old. What is the proper way to get this to work, ie not installing a really old package (seems like it was last in Ubuntu 12.04).

Also, trying to install it I got the following message:

```
Dependency is not satisfiable: libmng1 (>=1.0.3-1)
```

which I don't quite understand.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu/Debian/Linux/whatever is this software meant to work with? To me this sounds like a software, which depends on outdated libraries.

Comment: it's been tested with 12.04 nothing after. Am I all out of luck trying to use it in 14.04?

Comment: That package seems to not exist in ubuntu 14.04. If someone figures out a way to get it in 14.04 I'll consider this closed, otherwise please edit this or provide a different answer.

Comment: did you get it to work somehow in the end?